# Is this Tensorflow bias vector shaped correctly?

Tags: tensorflow, classification, logistic-regression

In the text I read the following:

[image: code]

I’m confused on the dimensions of the bias vector. How can we add a`(m,1)` vector to a`(1, p)` vector?  Is `w0` shaped correctly? Or should `w1` be shaped `(n, P)` to account for `P` classes, and the we broadcast `w0`?

Note: I assume `w1` should me `(n, P)` so that our matrix multiplication yields a row of unnormalized logits for each class prediction for each observation. Then does it make sense to add a per-class bias and broadcast that to the number of samples in our data?

I feel foolish for even asking but walking through the example I couldn’t reconcile...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, adding a (m,1) tensor to a (1, P) tensor gives a (m, P) tensor by broadcasting twice (giving that Y_hat at indices (i,j) is equal to tf.matmul(X, w1) at index i plus w0 at index j). However, this is not what should happen in feed forward network.

w1 should indeed be shaped (n, P) and then the bias is shaped correctly. tf.matmul(X, w1) has shape (m, P), and Y_hat has shape (m, P) using broadcasting as expected (since it should have the same shape as Y).